# Where are some good places to publish free flash fiction?

Tags: flash-fiction

[This question has been asked about *paying* markets](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/2348/where-can-i-find-paying-markets-for-flash-fiction), but does anyone know good places for putting up flash fiction just to build readership?

Answer (score 2):

Create a web site and publish them there.

Create a Facebook page and post them there.

Publish them in collections in ebook form. And in paperback, if you want to.

You don't need all that many to make a publishable collection. I've published standalone short stories as short as 3000 words. That makes for a pretty darned thin paperback, but I do sell a few copies.

I haven't tried [Wattpad](https://www.wattpad.com) myself, but a few writer friends of mine (whose stories sell way better than mine) swear by that for building readership.

Comment: Good suggestions. The problem with a website (which I have) is that it's hard to get people to just find it out of the blue.

Wattpad I just don't understand. It's so... stark. And I feel like it's full of teenagers. (Not that there's anything wrong with teenagers...)

Comment: True. You will have to market your work, just as if you had published it in some other way. The challenge is discoverability. Kristine Kathryn Rusch has a whole series of blog posts about that. http://kriswrites.com/business-rusch-publishing-articles/discoverability-series/

Answer (score 0):

Books of flash fiction usually list the places where the included pieces have been previously published. So you can safely assume that those journals accept flash. Send your stuff to those.

Might be a good idea to visit their websites to double-check.